# how to check which button pressed in php

Tags: php

i got following code i want to know which button pressed then pass the value to input box.

```
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="1" onclick="">Value1</button> 
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue1" value="2" onclick="">value 2 </button>

<?php
 if buttonpassvalue pressed then add the buttonpassvalue value

 <input type="text" name="value">
 else
 add value of buttonpassvalue1
 ?>
```

i am tried to solve but stock here.

please help me

thanks

Comment: are you sure you want php for this? Since that is going to involve a round trip to the server in order to figure out what buttons is pressed. are you looking for something like javascript?

Comment: tried with JavaScript doesn't work for me... any help .... i will give a try...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with Javascript.

As PHP is a server side language, it requires you to send some information to the server, meaning you would have to submit the form, and reload the page with the details of the request from the user.

With a javascript library like jQuery you can do something like the following.

```
<button class="some-button" value="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="some-button" value="2">Button 2</button>
<input type="hidden" name="buttonValue" class="button-value-hidden" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.some-button').on('click', function(){
        $('input.button-value-hidden').val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Now $_GET['buttonValue'] will contain your button value when the form is submitted.

Make sure you are including the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/)!

Comment: doesn't change the input value...in input on click... <input type="text" name="buttonValue" class="button-value-hidden" />